# How do I associate a string read from a file to an enum value?

Tags: c++, enums

**Problem**

I am somewhat unsure as to how an enum value is associated to a string input. My intent is to read in data from a file and once I get to a certain getline delimiter, the string should be associated with the taxCategory of the object in the array. I did look around at other SO threads but none of them showed how to associate other values with different enum values.

I saw that there could be a way of doing this with templates but I haven't learned anything about those just yet.

**Links for all of the code with line numbers**

GrItem.cpp http://pastebin.com/C4jmKcUt The lines with issues are 81 and 136.

StoreInfo.h http://pastebin.com/uh4armvs

**Quick code info**

This one is just intended to read the tax category as a string and save it to the correct taxCategory variable. I'm not sure if I should remove the delimiter from the string as I can do that later. However, if the determination of the string and the calculation of the tax amounts per taxCategory need to have them removed then I'll figure out a way.

```
// Read tax category
getline(nameFile, input, '#');
vectorList[count].taxCategory = input;// Casts string to a double
```

This one is just intended to print the tax category to the screen of the user. The intent is to have the string moved to the right side in a list format.

```
std::cout << vectorList[i].GrListItem::taxCategory << endl;// Print tax category
std::cout.width(20);
std::cout.fill(' ');
```

**Full code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StoreInfo.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

// Tax rate catagories
const double alcoholTax = 0.08;
const double foodTax = 0.05;
const double genMerchandiseTax = 0.07;
const double medicineTax = 0.04;

struct cost{
    double alcTax = 0.0, food = 0.0, genMerch = 0.0, meds = 0.0;// Total taxes collected for each tax bracket
    double totalTax = alcTax + food + genMerch + meds;// Total Taxes to be accessed later

    // Variables used in the accessor functions at the bottom
    double costBeforeTax = 0.0, costAfterTax = 0.0, custSaving = 0.0, totRegPrice = 0.0, totSalePrice = 0.0;
};

const int listSize = 20;
// Main method
int main(){

    string input;// Holds each line from the imported textfile temporarily
    string fileName;// Name of grocery list user wishes to use
    fstream nameFile;// File stream object
    GrListItem itemList[listSize];// Creates a list of objects. These objects are each item on the list and hold related information
    std::vector<GrListItem> vectorList(itemList, itemList + listSize);
    cost itemTotalCost;

    // Create a map from strin to enum
    std::map<std::string, taxCategory> EnumMap;
    EnumMap = enumMap;

    // Initialize
    EnumMap["alcohol"] = one;
    EnumMap["food"] = two;
    EnumMap["general merchansise"] = three;
    EnumMap["medicine"] = four;

    // Convert strings to enums
    std::string key = "alcohol";


    // Requests data from user
    cout << "What is the name of the grocery list you wish to use? " << endl;
    getline(cin, fileName);// Retrieves filename from user and applies string to grListName

    // Tests to see if file can be opened
    fstream testFile(fileName, ios::out);
    if (testFile.fail()){
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open indicated file.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    // Open data file
    nameFile.open(fileName, ios::in);
    // Read data and apply variables to an object
    if (nameFile){
        int count = 0;
        while (nameFile && count < listSize){

            // Read the name
            getline(nameFile, input, '#');
            vectorList[count].name = input;// Assigns item name to the object inside itemList.name

            // Read quantity
            getline(nameFile, input, '$');
            vectorList[count].quantity = atoi(input.c_str());// Casts string to an int

            // Read regular price
            getline(nameFile, input, '$');
            vectorList[count].regPrice = stof(input.c_str());// Casts string to a float

            // Read sale price
            getline(nameFile, input, '#');
            vectorList[count].salePrice = stof(input.c_str());

            // Read on sale bool
            getline(nameFile, input, '#');
            if (vectorList[count].onSale == 'Y')// If the item is on sale, the isOnSale var returns true 
                vectorList[count].isOnSale == 1;
            else
                vectorList[count].isOnSale == 0;
            vectorList[count].onSale = atoi(input.c_str());

            // Read tax category
            getline(nameFile, input, '#');
            vectorList[count].taxCategory = input;// Casts string to a double

            // These functions are called as many times as there are objects in the array. 
            getTotBeforeTax(vectorList[count].regPrice, vectorList[count].salePrice, vectorList[count].isOnSale);
            //getTotTaxCategory(taxCategory);
            getTotAfterTax(itemTotalCost.costBeforeTax, itemTotalCost.totalTax);

            count++;
        }
        // Close file
        nameFile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file.\n";

    // Sort array 
    // OFFER USER TO CHOOSE HOW THEY WOULD LIKE TO SORT THEIR LIST!!! For extra points
    // Maybe
    std::sort(vectorList.begin(), vectorList.end(), sortByName);

    // For loop that creates a receipt on the screen
    // Formatting may or may not be correct
    for (int i = 0; i != listSize; ++i){
        std::cout << vectorList[i].name << endl;// Print item name
        std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(20);
        std::cout.fill(' ');

        std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(5);// Print item quantity
        std::cout << vectorList[i].quantity << endl;
        std::cout.fill(' ');

        std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(5);// Print regular price of item
        std::cout << vectorList[i].regPrice << endl;// Adjust preci
        std::cout.fill(' ');

        std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(5);// Print sale price of item
        std::cout << vectorList[i].salePrice << endl;
        std::cout.fill(' ');

        if (vectorList[i].onSale == 1){
            std::cout << 'Y' << endl;// Print 'Y' if vectorList[i] is on sale
            std::cout.width(3);
            std::cout.fill(' ');
        }
        else {
            std::cout << 'N' << endl;// Print 'N' if vectorList[i] is not on sale
            std::cout.width(3);
            std::cout.fill(' ');
        }

        std::cout << vectorList[i].GrListItem::taxCategory << endl;// Print tax category
        std::cout.width(20);
        std::cout.fill(' ');
    }

    // Print details of purchase below list of bought items

    // NOTE: THESE VALUES ARE STORED IN THE STRUCT ABOVE main()
    // Display total before tax
    // Display total after tax
    // Display customer Savings

}

// Constructor
GrItem::GrItem(string name, int quantity, float regPrice, float salePrice, bool onSale, enum GrListItem::taxCategory taxCategory){

    name = name;
    quantity = quantity;
    regPrice = regPrice;
    salePrice = salePrice;
    onSale = onSale;
    enum GrListItem::taxCategory tax = taxCategory;

};

// Default constructor
GrItem::GrItem() {
}

// Associate the value of the item's tax based on the taxCategory enum
void calcTaxCategory(enum taxCat taxCat){

}

// Get the total cost before the tax
void getTotBeforeTax(double regPrice, double salePrice, bool onSale){
    cost itemTotalCost;
    if (onSale == 1){
        itemTotalCost.costBeforeTax += salePrice;
        itemTotalCost.totSalePrice += salePrice;
    }
    else{
        itemTotalCost.costBeforeTax += regPrice;
        itemTotalCost.totRegPrice += regPrice;
    }
}

// Get the total after tax
void getTotAfterTax(float costBeforeTax, float totalTax){
    cost itemTotalCost;
    itemTotalCost.costAfterTax = costBeforeTax + totalTax;
}

// Get the total amount of tax for each category
void getTotTaxCategory(enum taxCat taxCat){// These different values are determined by what enum tax category they are
    cost itemTotalCost;


}

// Get customer savings (total of all differences between regular price and sale price for items that are currently on sale)
void getCustSave(double totRegPrice, double totSalePrice, bool onSale){
    cost itemTotalCost;
    if (onSale == 1){
        itemTotalCost.custSaving = totRegPrice - totSalePrice;
    }

}

// Function that is called to sort by name
bool sortByName(const GrListItem &lhs, const GrListItem &rhs){
    return lhs.name < rhs.name;
}

// Function that is called to sort by quantity
bool sortByQuantity(const GrListItem &lhs, const GrListItem &rhs){
    return lhs.quantity < rhs.quantity;
}

// Function that is called to sort by regular price
bool sortByRegPrice(const GrListItem &lhs, const GrListItem &rhs){
    return lhs.regPrice < rhs.regPrice;
}

// Function that is called to sort by sale price
bool sortBySalePrice(const GrListItem &lhs, const GrListItem &rhs){
    return lhs.salePrice < rhs.salePrice;
}
```

Comment: I think you would be better off using a constant string array rather than enum - since the latter is known at compile time, and then it's converted to a symbolic internal representation.

Comment: @Floris Unfortunately if this was a personal project I would have done exactly that, alas this isn't a personal project so I have no choice in the matter.

Comment: I hate it when "requirements" specify _how_ you should do something - instead of what the desired output is. It says "I know how you should do your job" - which makes me think "then why don't you do my job for me"...

Comment: You may want to split up your gigantic main function into smaller functions to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: @Claptrap If I have enough time to make it more readable then I certainly shall. Or until I reach a point of "screw it, let's just make this easier"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to associate a string with an enum, there are several options available to you.  Here are two of them:

Option 1:  Use a const array of strings.  Scan for a match with your input and cast the index of the matching string to the enum value.  (handle the no match case, of course)

```
enum MyEnum {one, two, three, error};
const char * stringToEnum[] = 
    {"One", "Two", "Three"};
string key = "Two"; // for example
MyEnum e = error;
for(size_t index = 0; index < (sizeof(stringToEnum)/sizeof(stringToEnum[0])); ++index)
{
   if(key == stringToEnum[index])
   {
      e = MyEnum(index);
      break;
   }
}
```

Option 2: Create a map from string to enum.  Requires run-time initialization, but the code to resolve the value is dead-easy:

Declare the map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum MyEnum {error, one, two, three};
typedef std::map<std::string, MyEnum> EnumMap;
EnumMap enumMap;
```

Initialize the map:

```
int main()
{
    enumMap["One"] = one;
    enumMap["Two"] = two;   
    enumMap["Three"] = three;
```

Use the map to convert strings to enums First with the [] operator:

```
    std::string key = "Two";
    std::cout << key << "=" << enumMap[key] << std::endl;
    key = "Three";
    std::cout << key << "=" << enumMap[key] << std::endl;
    // this will add a bogus entry to the table
    // do not use [] if your input may contain bad keys.
    key = "Five";
    std::cout << key << "=" << enumMap[key] << std::endl;
```

Here's the output so far:

```
Two=2
Three=3
Five=0
```

Now try the same thing with the at() mehtod:

```
    key = "Two";
    std::cout << "At: " << key << "=" << enumMap.at(key) << std::endl;
    key = "Three";
    std::cout << "At: " << key << "=" << enumMap.at(key) << std::endl;
    // this will find the zero entry added by the [] operator
    key = "Five";
    std::cout << "At: "  << key << "=" << enumMap.at(key) << std::endl;
    // this will throw an exception
    key = "Seven";
    std::cout << "At: "  << key << "=" << enumMap.at(key) << std::endl;
```

And here's the output using the at() method:

```
At: Two=2
At: Three=3
At: Five=0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  map::at
```

Comment: @koodeta I edited the answer to make it more clear how it applies to your question.

Comment: (I'm using the second method) Is there an #include that is required for this? I use #include <map> but it doesn't seem to work for the map declaration. With MyEnum, do I just place the enum identifier in there? Because I did so and I'm getting an undefined identifier error. enumMap is getting the same thing but I assume it's from the initial declaration. When it comes to the enumMap["One
"] = one; What do you mean by one? Is it a previously declared variable?

Comment: What if the enum I declared is in the header though? How would I call it? I've changed the code on display to show what I currently have.